# Insert nested JSON in 2 SQL tables in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following sample JSON and am trying to insert it into 2 tables called Order and OrderLines. There could be 100 records coming in at a time in the form of JSON array. 
How do I deserialize it and insert rows from this in 2 SQL tables viz order and orderlines?

```
{
    "OrderID":"123466",
    "WebOrderID":"0",
    "PersonID":"13",
    "BillToAddressType":"Business Address",
    "ShipToAddressType":"Temp Address",
    "OrderLineItems":
    [
        {
            "ProductID":"123",
            "Quantity":"1",
            "Price":"50.00",
            "BadgeLastName":"BLName",
            "BadgeFirstName":"BFName",
            "BadgeCompanyName":"BCompany",
            "OrderLinePromo":"",
            "CourseInfo":[{"CourseID":"2","ClassID":"1"}],
        },
        {
            "ProductID":"233",
            "Quantity":"1",
            "Price":"50.00",
            "BadgeLastName":"",
            "BadgeFirstName":"",
            "BadgeCompanyName":"",
            "OrderLinePromo":"CheapBookDeal"            

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Newton.Soft from nuget package manager. 

Use it to Deserialize the string to an object. 
Once you have an object, use an interface to map your Json object, or a mapper, into a database entity object. And then you store it.Easy enough with entity-framework as an ORM f.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object `class` in c#, set the `properties` to the names in `json` file, and deserialize the `json` into the `class`

```
public class ClassName {
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int WebOrderId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    etc......
}
```

Reference `Newtonsoft.Json` library. Then deserialize

```
var values = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(json);
```

Now for debugging create an instance of the `class` and step over every `property` to ensure the values are correct

```
ClassName newObject = new ClassName();
newObject.OrderId = values.OrderId;
newObject.WebOrderId = values.WebOrderId;
newObject.PersonId = values.WebOrderId;
etc........
```

Depending on the fields in the `json` file, you may need to specify the names in the c# `class`, just above each `property` in the `class` just include the `[JsonProperty("JsonFieldName")]` attribute in case it happens to be case sensitive and c# can't read it into the `class`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer how to write this info to database after deserializing?

Comment: If you have a database context, like `DatabaseClassName context;`. Then just do `context.Add(newObject);`
`context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: How to reference the `DatabaseClassName` and save it depends on the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json from NUGET Package Manager.

If the JSON always has the same properties, then create a class which also has the same data model. This allows you to deserialize it really easily with a call to `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`:

```
T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

Where T is your C# class.

Answer (score 0):

Create . Net class  to set  Json  data.  And deserialize  Json data into  class  using newtonsoft.